# jQuery jScrollPane only works with text

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, scrollbar, jscrollpane

I am trying to use [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) to scroll through my gallery that is inside of an `iframe`. I am using the jQuery code for iframe scrolling from the [official example](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/iframe.html).
Using this code doesn't work for my images (it just hides the original browser scrollbars, doesn't throw any errors and refuses to scroll), but it works perfectly if I replace my images with multiple paragraphs so they overflow (just like in the example).
**EDIT**: I forgot to mention that images scroll perfectly using the default browser scrollbar.
**EDIT #2**: Made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RLVrX/1/).

Here's how my gallery is structured:

```
...
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">  // Used the same way as in the example, works with text
 <div class="gallery">

  <div class='picture'>
   <img class='pin' src='something'/>
    <div class='wrapper'>
     <img class='thumbnail' src='something'/>
     <img class='border' src='something' />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='picture'>
  ...
  </div>

 </div>
</div>
...
```

And here's the CSS for gallery and pictures:

```
.gallery {
 position: relative;
 width: 98%;
}
.picture {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 display: list-item;
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 11%;
}
.picture .pin {
 position: absolute;
 left: 48%;
 width: 13%;
}
.picture .thumbnail {
 position: absolute;
 width: 89%;
 margin-top: 19%;
}
.picture .border {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
}
```

I ignored margins and some other irrelevant stuff, but you get the idea.
The jQuery code is exactly the same as presented in the [example](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/iframe.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!
Apparently, the script didn't like the `absolute` position of my `.picture .pin`. Changing it to `relative` and restyling a bit solved my issue.
[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RLVrX/3/)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that images are loaded after scrollbar is initialized, and scrollbar does not detect container size changes by default. If you read documentation carefully, you can see next:

> [Demo](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/image.html) showing how [autoReinitialise](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/settings.html#autoReinitialise)  can also be used so that content
>   with images in it displays correctly in jScrollPane

So, try `autoReinitialise` option. If it won't help - update your question with example of your iframe on jsFiddle.net

Comment: Tried adding 'autoReinitialise': true in jScrollPane settings, but nothing seems to change. Still no errors.